# What is the best way to propogate Aralia nudicaulis (Wild Sarsaparilla)?

Tags: propagation, native

I grew up with this plant covering the forest floors around my neck of the woods on Eastern Long Island, NY.

I have never seen it for sale, even at one of the many native plant nurseries we regularly buy from.

There is some information online about propagation, but it all seems fairly vague.

Has anyone grown this from seed, runner, or other means? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

I've never grown it, but this link here https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=ARNU2 talks about propagation, and suggests that it is commercially available, scroll down for full information. The secondary embedded link advises that the seeds need around 60-70 days of cold, moist stratification, so if you can't source plants, then division of the root as advised would be best.